# Yii2 Listview dynamically update dataProvider

Tags: yii2, pjax

I have a Listview of which I'd like to dynamically update the `dataProvider` with the click of a button.

`itemController.php`:

```
  <?php
    public function actionList($category = ''){
      $this->layout = '_notags';
      $query['published'] = 1;
      if(!empty($category)){
        $category = category::findOne(['title'=>$category])->id;
        $query['category_id'] = $category;
      }

        echo "<script>console.log('$category')</script>";

      $items = new ActiveDataProvider([
                    'query' => Item::find()->where($query)->orderBy('date_created DESC'),
                    'pagination' => [
                        'pageSize' => 9
                    ],
                  ]);
      return $this->render('_fresh', [
          'newitems' => $items,
          'category' => $category
      ]);
    }
    ?>
```

`_list.php`:

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use kop\y2sp\ScrollPager;
use yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

if(empty($category))
$genre = '';

$listview = ListView::widget([
      'id' => 'freshitems',
       'dataProvider' => $newitems,
       'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'col-xs-4 featured-item-'.$category],
       'itemView' => '_item',
       'pager' => ['negativeMargin'=>250, 'delay'=>0, 'spinnerSrc'=> '/img/loading.png','triggerOffset' => 3, 'class' => ScrollPager::className(), 'item'=>'.featured-item-' . $genre, 'enabledExtensions'=> Array( ScrollPager::EXTENSION_TRIGGER, ScrollPager::EXTENSION_SPINNER, ScrollPager::EXTENSION_NONE_LEFT, ScrollPager::EXTENSION_PAGING ) ],
       //'summary' => false
  ]);

  $this->registerJsFile('@web/js/main.js');
  $this->registerJsFile('@web/js/jquery.quickfit.js');

  Pjax::begin(['id'=>'freshitems']);
      echo HtmlPurifier::process(
       $listview
     );
  Pjax::end();

?>
```

`main.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".category-select").click("pjax:end", function() {
      $.pjax.reload({container:"#freshitems"});  //Reload GridView
  });
});
```

**I tried using jQuery to change the div containing _list:**

`index.php:`
    Some Category
    
    $this->render('_list.php', $category)

`main.js`:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('#list-container').load("item/list/" + $(this).id;
});
```

**Doing this does change the listview, but it glitches the ScrollPager plugin (infinite scroller no longer works properly).**

What would be the best way to dynamically change a Listview's dataProvider (or listView completely) in my view?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem if so could you possibly update the question with the answer. Thanks

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an AJAX request to an action on your controller, from there return a rendered (preferably in a new view file, with a DataProvider it receives as a parameter) and empty the HTML then append it.
Assuming you put the ListView inside of a container with some id to make it easier.

Comment: Hi I tried to get values using ajax request. I get it in console window .how to display it in yii2 gridview. please visit this link and answer the question if possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667393/how-to-populate-gridview-from-ajax-call-using-yii2