# how to populate gridview from ajax call using Yii2

Tags: json, yii2

In my project, I have created a search box. when I type something and click the button "get info" I get all information in console window using ajax call. now I want to populate this data in yii2 gridview. data will different at every runtime. I want to give this data to $dataprovider of gridview is it possible??

here is code-
CompaniesController.php

```
public function actionCompanyinfo(){     

    $text_in_search = $_GET['text_in_search'];
    $left_items_cat = ltrim($_GET['left_items_cat']);

    if($left_items_cat == "Companies"){

         $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select(['c.name', 'c.id'])
                ->from(['companies as c'])
                ->where('c.name LIKE :query') 
                ->addParams([':query'=>'%'.$text_in_search.'%'])
                ->all(); 

        $response['comapnies_matching'] = $query;
            return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
        $response
    ]);  

    }
}
```

companies/index.php

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
 $typeahead = $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]);

$getinfobtn = Html::SubmitButton( 'Get info', [ 'class' => 'btn btn-success' , 'id' =>'getinfo']) ;
   ActiveForm::end();
```

myjsfile.js

```
$("#getinfo").click(function(){
        var text_in_search = $("#companies-name").val();
        var left_items_cat = $('#left-items li.active').text();
        var url = "index.php?r=companies/companyinfo";

        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {text_in_search,left_items_cat},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {           
             // $( "#country"+id ).html(data[0].countries);
             console.log(data[0]);
           // **want to show this data in yii2 grid view**
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An error occured!');
            alert('Error in ajax request');
        }
    });
```

console window

```
comapnies_matching
:
Array(3)
0
:
{name: "ADC Therapeutics Sarl", id: "402"}
1
:
{name: "ADC Therapeutics Sarl", id: "407"}
2
:
{name: "ADC Therapeutics Sarl", id: "412"}
```

how to show/ populate this data in gridview??

Comment: Instead of JSON try to return the full HTML Gridview. Don't forget to remove dataType json from your ajax.

Comment: @SarathE how? ?

Comment: Did you know Render Partial method? This will generate an HTML without layout. Please check the link.  http://www.bsourcecode.com/2013/04/render-and-renderpartial-in-yii/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650590/how-to-show-json-data-in-yii2-gridview/47652916#47652916 duplicated

Answer (score 1):

CompaniesController.php

```
public function actionCompanyinfo(){     

$text_in_search = $_GET['text_in_search'];
$left_items_cat = ltrim($_GET['left_items_cat']);

if($left_items_cat == "Companies"){

     $dataProvider= (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['c.name', 'c.id'])
            ->from(['companies as c'])
            ->where('c.name LIKE :query') 
            ->addParams([':query'=>'%'.$text_in_search.'%'])
            ->all(); 

    return $this->renderPartial('gridview', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]); 

}}
```

You need to render the gridview in gridview.php view file

myjsfile.js

```
$("#getinfo").click(function(){
    var text_in_search = $("#companies-name").val();
    var left_items_cat = $('#left-items li.active').text();
    var url = "index.php?r=companies/companyinfo";

    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    data: {text_in_search,left_items_cat},
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {           
         //set the ajax response as your html content 
         $('#myDiv').html(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('An error occured!');
        alert('Error in ajax request');
    }
});
```

Comment: tried the above code .. output is...error in ajax request..whose id is this #myDiv

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: `myDiv` I given as an example you can give your own id

Comment: alert('Error in ajax request');.. displays this in alertbox

Comment: Call that ajax URL directly in browser then you can see the real errors (If it has any PHP errors). and also check the jqXHR in alertbox.

Answer (score 1):

You could render and return HTML of the Gridview from your controller, and then when you get the response. put the HTML code where you want to display it, probably where the current Gridview is contained.

Edit, added code example:

```
public function actionCompanyinfo(){
    $requestData = \Yii::$app->request->get();
    $text_in_search = isset($requestData['text_in_search']) ? $requestData['text_in_search'] : "";
    $left_items_cat = isset($requestData['left_items_cat']) ? trim($requestData['text_in_search']) : "";

    if($left_items_cat == "Companies"){
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['c.name', 'c.id'])
            ->from(['companies as c'])
            ->where('c.name LIKE :query')
            ->addParams([':query'=>'%'.$text_in_search.'%']),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]);

        return \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                // your columns here...
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

On your VIEW file you should create an area (possible  element
And then in your js file where you are making the AJAX request, make sure the response does something like:

```
function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {           
    $("#show-grid-here").html(data); //or data[0], I'm not sure. try both.
},
```

Comment: can you help by some code. I am quit new to yii2. and I does not write code for gridview as i want to show on button click.

Comment: Show me your current code in the controller (The action that you call to retrieve the data) and also the code which makes the request and uses the response (Javascript, probably on your view file)

Comment: action companyinfo .. given in the question

Comment: Do you have an initial Grid which you are trying to filter? Or is this the first time you present it? If it's not the first time, show me action that shows the grid first time.

Comment: I edited my original post for your needs, let me know how it worked out for you.
Also, you might want to create a view file which includes the code for generating the grid, and receives the dataProvider from the controller. Then you would have to return renderAjax of that page. But first thing try with given simple example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160699/discussion-between-tal-kitron-and-goli).

Comment: Well you never came so I guess you solved it. Please mark as correct solution, or ask anything further if you require

Comment: Come to the chat then, look 4 comments up and join